# Multiples of 'k' less than 'n'

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How many positive integer multiples of a rational number k exist, that are less than a rational number n?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  And I assume $k$ is positive as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Write $k=\frac{a}{b}$ and $n=\frac{p}{q}$ with $a,b,p,q$ positive integers. Can you use this to reduce to the case where $k$ and $n$ are actually positive integers themselves?

---

Observe that for any positive integer $h$
$$
hk\leq n \iff h\frac{a}{b}\leq\frac{p}{q} \iff hqa\leq pb
$$
Now you can show (try to do so!) that there are exactly
$$
\left\lfloor\frac{pb}{qa}\right\rfloor
=\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor
$$
such integers $h$.

Comment: No, I didn't quite understand what you are saying. How would reducing to the case where both are integers help?

Comment: Assume $k,n$ are positive integers. Can you compute how many positive integers $h$ are there such that $hk\leq n$?

Comment: OK, got it! there are floor(n/k) positive integers h such that hk <= n because floor(n/k) gives you how many times k goes into n completely.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both $k$ and $n$ are positive.

The positive integer multiplies of $k$ are

$$k,2k,3k,\dots,qk,pk,\dots$$

And let $pk\le n\lt qk$ where $q=p+1$

Or equivalently, $$p\le\frac{n}{k}\lt p+1$$

In other words, $p$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $n/k$. By definition, this is the greatest integer function.

$$\left \lfloor \frac{n}{k}\right \rfloor$$